# Manage users in Trac

Tags: passwords, username

Is there a convenient way to manage users (add user, change passwords, etc.) with [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)?

Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. [AccountManagerPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin). From the docs:

> - allow users to register new accounts
> - login via an HTML form instead of using HTTP authentication
> - allow existing users to change their passwords or delete their accounts
> - send a new password to users who’ve forgotten their password
> - administration of user accounts